# how to check the scrolling of div within its parent div when window size is reduced

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, media-queries

I am using bootstrap to design web application. I have two main divs, sidebar div with span 2 which has `position : fixed` and right div which is of span 10. These divs has `float : left` property as per bootstrap css file as I am using `row-fluid` class.
So the problem I am facing is when window size is reduced after certain limit, user is able to scroll the content of right div and which is overlapping with left div. So I want hide the content of right div which overlaps on left div ( ie. left div, the fixed div, should behave like a left wall of browser window for right div).
I have tried using overflow property and also tried changing z-index of divs, but nothing seems to be working here.
[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Omsai/5Gwvs/1/)   - here is the  link I have reproduced the problem, there if you scroll left in result area, you can see the content of right div is overlapping with left div(nav list), as I have given `left-margin : 240px` to rightDiv. So what I want is, the right div content should not overlap left div, and it should be hidden behind.
Any suggestion on how to get it right or is there any other way to achieve the same?

Comment: instead of trying to explain things like i have something here and there, the actual code, or sample of actual code with which we can reproduce the problem or something like a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would be much better to understand the problem..

Comment: if they are position fixed then float doesn't matter

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2FVLh/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure exactly what you are trying to do. If it's just hiding whatever is overlapping then applying a `background-color` to the fixed div will achieve this.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Gwvs/2/).

Answer (score 0):

You can left padding equal to the width of left navigation to prevent the overlapping (*imitate*)

```
padding-left:140px;
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Gwvs/5/)